# ExtJS: Applying a Messagbox only to a specific window (modal)?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have the following code and while it is working, the modal part is over the entire browser window.  I have create my own xtype: window and wish to only have it affect this part. I have tried RenderTo but that produces strange results.

Does anyone know how?

Here is my existing code:

```
msg.show({
    msg: 'Attempting to create account...',
    progressText: 'creating...',
    width:420,
    wait:true,
    waitConfig: {interval:150}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in this principle:

```
parentwindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window');

msg = Ext.create('Ext.yourownwindow', {
    msg: 'Attempting to create account...',
    progressText: 'creating...',
    width:420,
    wait:true,
    waitConfig: {interval:150}
});

parentwindow.add(msg);
msg.show();
```